# Calculating ticks of TimeSpan

Tags: c#

I have a list of `Keyframe`s, which are just objects with TimeSpans and
a field (type long) which has the own timeSpan's ticks called `tempTicks`.
The full list goes from Keyframe 1 - 7000.

And almost every keyframe has a greater timestamp than the one before.
**I would like grab those keyframes from 300-800 and I would like to give them 
a new TimeSpan beginning from 0 ticks.**

```
List<Keyframe> region = new List<Keyframe>();

long highestTicks = 0;
long durationTicks = 0; //Stores the whole duration of this new region

//beginFrame and endFrame are 300 and 800
for (int i = beginFrame; i < endFrame; i += 1)
{
    //Clip is the full list of keyframes
    Keyframe k = clip.Keyframes[i];
    if (region.Count < 1)
    {
        k.Time = TimeSpan.FromTicks(0);
    }
    else
    {
        //This is the trouble-part
        if (k.Time.Ticks > highestTicks)
        {
           highestTicks = k.Time.Ticks;
           k.Time = 
           TimeSpan.FromTicks(highestTicks - region[region.Count -1].tempTicks);
        }

     }
     durationTicks += k.Time.Ticks;
     region.Add(k);
}
```

I don't get all of them correctly this way.
Do you see why?

**Example: Taking a favorite scene of a movie. You want to export it in a way that the scene starts from 0:00 in your media player, not from 87:00, from where you originally took it.**

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me... You start talking about having timespans and then start referring to timestamps. The two are very different. A timespan measures a duration of time (ie between two points) and a timestamp is a single point in time. ARe you just talking about changing anything with a timestamp of 300-800 to having one between 0 and 500? It might be worth giving some examples of before and after values to make it clear what you want...

Comment: Maybe the timespan is not the time between frames but each frame's time from zero.

Comment: Sry Chris. I meant timeSpans.
Example: In my question now.

@Steve: the timespan is relative to the timeline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
var tickOffset = clip.Keyframes[beginFrame].Time.Ticks;
// this is your 'region' variable
var adjustedFrames = clip.Keyframes
    .Skip(beginFrame)
    .Take(endFrame - beginFrame)
    .Select(kf => new Keyframe { 
        Time = TimeSpan.FromTicks(kf.Time.Ticks - tickOffset),
        OtherProperty = kf.OtherProperty            
    })
    .ToList();
var durationTicks = adjustedFrames.Max(k => k.Time.Ticks);
```

Comment: You can set a list of properties in the initializer, or you can use the constructor on Keyframe directly (but you didn't post the class, so don't know what other values it might have). Updated code to show how you might set other properties.

Comment: Incredible stuff man! Thanks that works like a breeze. Could you but tell me, how people like you call this kind of way of making a list this efficient? I'd like to learn about it

Comment: It's called LINQ. Basically just extension methods that allow you to chain operations on anything IEnumerable. Lots of examples online and on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of weird to be modifying the times for those frames in-place. One would expect that you'd extract them to a new list and not modify the original values. Nevertheless, the way to do it is to use the first field as the "base" and just subtract that value from all the others. So if your times are `[..., 27, 28, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, ...]` and you want to change the values from 27 to 39, they become: `[0, 1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12]`:

```
List<Keyframe> region = new List<Keyframe>();

long highestTicks = 0;
long durationTicks = 0; //Stores the whole duration of this new region

long baseTicks = clip.Keyframes[beginFrame].Time.Ticks;

//beginFrame and endFrame are 300 and 800
for (int i = beginFrame; i <= endFrame; i += 1)
{
    //Clip is the full list of keyframes
    Keyframe k = clip.Keyframes[i];
    k.Time = TimeSpan.FromTicks(k.Time.Ticks - baseTicks);
    highestTicks = Math.Max(highestTicks, k.Time.Ticks);

     region.Add(k);
}

durationTicks = highestTicks;
```

Although I really don't understand why you're worrying about ticks. You can do your math on `TimeSpan` values directly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the "i" value runs from 300 to 799. Do you need a <= operator?

Comment: Didn't really change anything

Comment: Is clip.Keyframes zero based? If so, are you really looking for "i" values of 299 through 799?

Comment: Yes, what's the matter with that?

Comment: Nothing, assuming that the value of beginFrame is 299 and endFrame is 800 in your code, you should be iterating through each key frame.